# GetOrgChart - 'Responsive'ness

Tags: mobile, getorgchart

Two issues when I try to view an org chart on a mobile platform:
1. Scaling doesn't seem to be appropriate (looks way too small)
2. The 'canvas' is not being calculated correctly (it cuts off halfway down the screen).

Screenshot attached

Anyone else looking at this on a mobile platform?

[image]